# Dojo: MVC.at does not work in dijit.form.Selects

Tags: model-view-controller, select, dojo

I am trying to link up the value of a dijit.form.Select to a ListController. I have it working with FilteringSelects and TextBoxes, but it won't work with regular Selects.

I am writing an editor for a list of records. I am using the ListController to represent the list of records, and I want all my widgets to be able to edit the "current record". Each widget, therefore, binds to a different property in the ListController. Then I will be able to switch between the different records, but use the same widgets to edit them.

The controller of course has an idea of which record is the current one, and some of the widgets work. So when I edit, say, the Barcode field with a TextBox widget, the ListController sets the value on the correct record.

However I haven't been able to hook up the Select widget's value to its intended property in the ListController.

I have tried putting the value: mvc.at( controller, 'field' ) in the constructor as well setting it directly after the call, but no dice. Any ideas?

```
require( [ 'dijit/form/Select', ], function( Select ) {
    var testSelect = new Select( {
        value: mvc.at( controller, 'field' ), // controller is a ListController
        store: store,
        searchAttr: "description", 
        labelAttr:  "description"
    }, 'TestSelect' );
} );


require( [ 'dijit/form/Select', ], function( Select ) {
    var testSelect = new Select( {
        store: store,
        searchAttr: "description", 
        labelAttr:  "description"
    }, 'TestSelect' );
    testSelect.set( 'value', mvc.at( controller, 'field' ) );
} );
```

How does mvc.at() actually work? It doesn't seem to set the value property to an mvc.at value, even on the widgets that do work. There seems to be some winking and nudging going on inside the widget code. Something about _refs?

Answer (score 2):

A dijit/form/Select value is expecting a single value, but a ListController holds an array so you can not directly bind a field in a ListController to a Select's value.  You could place the Select inside of a dojox/mvc/Group which has something like this: 
data-dojo-props="target: at(controller,'cursor')"

And then you would setup your select with something like this:
value: mvc.at( 'rel:', 'field' ),

And anytime the cursor or cursorIndex is changed on the Controller the select would be updated.

If you want to set the value directly from the controller, I think you would have to do something like this:
value: mvc.at( controller.model[0], 'field' ),

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what the problem is, but I'll try that mvc/Group idea. Thanks!